# Environment configuration for different Debug and Release framework - Xcode

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

Simply i have two frameworks from a payment provider, they provide `Debug` and `Release` frameworks, to be used for different environments.

I was trying to configure/find out on the web of a way that i can configure the import of both of them in one scheme, and depending on the `Build Configuration` it will switch between `Debug` and `Release` framework.

I played with `Framework Search path` for example `Debug` to have debug url to framework, and the same for `Release` to link to release framework url to file.

Im looking for something more usable and easy such as run script, or stying away from manual import for each build configuration.

**Note:** Framework has the same name, as well as the framework is build with objective-c without single header import.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below approach,

- Create a new folder "Frameworks" in the project directory where .xcodeproj exists.
- Place release framework in /Frameworks/Release/arm64/
- Place debug framework in /Frameworks/Debug/x86_64/

Paste below script in Build Phases -> Run Script:

```
cp -r "$PROJECT_DIR/Frameworks/$CONFIGURATION/$ARCHS" "$PROJECT_DIR/"
rm -dfR <Name of the framework> && \
cp -pRP "$ARCHS" <Name of the frameowrk> && \
rm -rf "$ARCHS"
```

Comment: Do i need to import them as embedded frameworks , or just add this code ?

Comment: @nataMio Yes.You need to add framework in Embedded frameworks. Above script will replace the framework based on selected configuration on compilation.

Comment: its not ideal solution.

Comment: You can try solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400086/xcode-add-embedded-binary-with-buildscript and use $CONFIGURATION to embed debug and release frameworks

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it suits your needs, but you can try

```
#if DEBUG
 import debugFramework
#else
 import releaseFramework
#endif
```